# block ui when I run the task code?

Tags: c#

this code when i run the code 
the ui form block what the problem  .the ui form block

```
private  void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t1 = new Task( check2);
    Task t2 = new Task( check2);
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
}

private  void check2()
{           
    for (int  a=0 ; a <= 100000; a++)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(a);
        }
     }                       
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Your code sends 200000 blocks of code to UI thread to handle. It can’t do anything else than handle them which causes blocking. If it were a single block it would be much faster at least

Comment: You are asking too much of a Control to add 200000 items so quickly. I would not add that many items ever, but you can try adding items to a collection and then binding to the list when you have built the collection.

Comment: Use async programming, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587832/prevent-winforms-ui-block-when-using-async-await

Comment: win form @Evertude

Comment: True it will be much faster but I will put more than TASK so how can I block the form blocking when executing @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: In this case I will create more methode when using more than task @Crowcoder

Comment: What is the task doing? Does it need to run in the UI thread?

Comment: You could use `.BeginInvoke`, passing a `List` or a `Stack` (inverted) of objects to the `ListBox.AddRange()` method, in a `.BeginUpdate();` / `.EndUpdate();` sequence. The `ListBox` probably won't like those many items, but it will not block.