# Amazon S3 loading Issue in upload file in multipart

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I upload a file using Amazon S3 multipart then it's loading, the file is not successfully uploaded. `uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent` in this function facing loading problem after `e.PercentDone` is 100, web page is loading infinity time.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

                    Stream st = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);
                    string fExt = Path.GetExtension(name);

                    string strRes = String.Concat(fName, builder.ToString());
                    string strRes1 = String.Concat(strRes, fExt);

                    string s3FileName = @strRes1;
                    stt = st;
                    fileNameInS3 = s3FileName;
                    bool a;
                    TrackMPUAsync().Wait();

            }
        }
         public async Task TrackMPUAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
                // Use TransferUtilityUploadRequest to configure options.
                // In this example we subscribe to an event.
                TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest =
                    new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + foldername,
                        Key = filename,
                        InputStream = fileInputStrem
                    };

                uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent +=
                     new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>
                         (uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);


                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
                Console.WriteLine("Upload completed");
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
        }

      public void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(object sender, 
      UploadProgressArgs e)
        {
            // Process event.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
        }
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions for getting to a working solution, but to be honest I didn't run your code (this is based on reviewing it quickly). First, the `BucketName` property must be set to the exact name of the bucket[1], so you shouldn't be adding the folder name to it. Instead, the folder name should be added as the prefix on the `Key`:

```cs
BucketName = bucketName,
Key = foldername + @"/" + filename,
```

Next, using `Console.WriteLine` may may it difficult to see the errors caught. It appears this is part of an WinForms application, so perhaps using `Debug.WriteLine()`[2] to display the errors in Visual Studio (or Code, etc.) would be a good idea.

Finally, and perhaps importantly, the use of `TrackMPUAsync().Wait()` in the event handler is synchronous and will block until the upload completes[3], instead you may want to perform the upload asynchronously:

```cs
Task.Run(() => TrackMPUAsync());
```

Hope this is helpful.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline

[3] [Prevent winforms UI block when using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587832/prevent-winforms-ui-block-when-using-async-await)

Comment: Hi, when I using this 'Task.Run(() => TrackMPUAsync());' instated of TrackMPUAsync().Wait() this code then , TrackMPUAsync() this function is not executing. 
and how to update e.percentdone value to label.


public void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
            Label1.Text=e.percentdone;
        }

above code is not working while a file is uploading on aws s3. It shows value when e.percentdone is 100.